# select atleast one item to submit the form

Tags: javascript, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

I was trying to validate the form using bootstrap and angularjs.
I have the two group of checkboxes which I want to validate. User should select atleast one checkbox from each group so that Submit button is enabled and the values are submitted.

Demo: https://plnkr.co/edit/m5erCJINS1sj70FxInd4?p=preview

In the above demo, User should select atleast one from RED,BLUE and one from Mac1,Mac2 to make SubmitValue button enabled and user can submit the data.

sample code:

```
<form name="eltForm">
    <h4>--FORM VALIDATION--</h4>
    <div class="btn-group" name="color">
        <label class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" ng-model="model1.prod1" uib-btn-checkbox="prod1">RED
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-info-sign"></span>
        </label>
        <label class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" ng-model="model1.prod2" uib-btn-checkbox="prod2">BLUE
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-info-sign"></span>
        </label>
        <div ng-show="eltForm.$submitted || eltForm.color.$touched">
            <p class="error-mesg" ng-show="eltForm.color.$error.required">Please Select the Color.</p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="btn-group" style="margin: 0 3px;padding: 5px;" name="machines">
        <label class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" ng-model="model2.item1" uib-btn-checkbox="item1">Mac1
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-info-sign"></span>
        </label>
        <label class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" ng-model="model2.item2" uib-btn-checkbox="item2">Mac2
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-info-sign"></span>
        </label>
        <div ng-show="eltForm.$submitted || eltForm.machines.$touched">
            <p class="error-mesg" ng-show="eltForm.machines.$error.required">Please Select the Machines.</p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="btn-group">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-xs" style="margin: 13px;" ng-click="submitValue()" ng-disabled="myForm.$invalid">SubmitValue</button>
    </div>
</form>
```

Comment: have you tried using a radio button instead?

Comment: Requirement is I want to select atleast one item from each group before user click on submit button. So I want to disable the submit button and after user selects atleast one checkbox from RED/BLUE and Mac1 or Mac2 I want to enable the submit button.  I tried using ng-disabled="myForm.$invalid" in submit button but that doesn't seem to work.

Answer (score 0):

```
 $scope.submitValue = function(){
   if(($scope.model1.prod1 || $scope.model1.prod2 )&& ($scope.model2.item1 || $scope.model2.item2))
   alert('Hi');
 }
```

please Change your controller to above code.

check [here](https://plnkr.co/edit/WywgTrny8qef9CZG3AGR?p=preview)

Answer (score 0):

all you need id to add an `ng-disabled`  field to the `button` and tag it to a field on `$scope` eg: `$scope.buttonDisabled = true;` which'll disable the button and add `ng-click` on `label or button` and check the `model` value based on condition and set/re-set the `$scope.buttonDisabled` field.

```js
var myApp = angular.module('app', ['ui.bootstrap']);
myApp.controller('dataCtrl', function($scope, $uibModal) {
  'use strict';
  $scope.buttonDisabled = true;
  $scope.model1 = {
    prod1: false,
    prod2: false,

  };
  $scope.model2 = {
    item1: false,
    item2: false,

  };

  $scope.clicked = function() {
    if (($scope.model1.prod1 || $scope.model1.prod2) && ($scope.model2.item1 || $scope.model2.item2)) {
      $scope.buttonDisabled = false;
    }
  }
  $scope.submitValue = function() {
    if (($scope.model1.prod1 || $scope.model1.prod2) && ($scope.model2.item1 || $scope.model2.item2)) {
      alert('VALID')
    }
  }
});
```

```css
.btn span.glyphicon {
  opacity: 0;
}

.btn.active span.glyphicon {
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <link data-require="bootstrap-css@*" data-semver="3.3.6" rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.css" />
  <script data-require="angular.js@1.5.0" data-semver="1.5.0" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.0/angular.js"></script>
  <script src="//angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/ui-bootstrap-tpls-1.2.4.js"></script>
  <script src="script.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
</head>

<body ng-app="app" ng-controller="dataCtrl">

  <form name="eltForm">
    <h4>--FORM VALIDATION--</h4>
    <div class="btn-group" name="color">
      <label class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" ng-click="clicked()" ng-model="model1.prod1" uib-btn-checkbox="prod1">RED
<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-info-sign"></span>
    </label>
      <label class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" ng-click="clicked()" ng-model="model1.prod2" uib-btn-checkbox="prod2">BLUE
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-info-sign"></span>
    </label>
      <div ng-show="eltForm.$submitted || eltForm.color.$touched">
        <p class="error-mesg" ng-show="eltForm.color.$error.required">Please Select the Color.</p>
      </div>

    </div>
    <div class="btn-group" style="margin: 0 3px;padding: 5px;" name="machines">
      <label class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" ng-click="clicked()" ng-model="model2.item1" uib-btn-checkbox="item1">Mac1
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-info-sign"></span>
    </label>
      <label class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" ng-click="clicked()" ng-model="model2.item2" uib-btn-checkbox="item2">Mac2
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-info-sign"></span>
    </label>
      <div ng-show="eltForm.$submitted || eltForm.machines.$touched">
        <p class="error-mesg" ng-show="eltForm.machines.$error.required">Please Select the Machines.</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="btn-group">
      <button type="button" ng-disabled="buttonDisabled" class="btn btn-primary btn-xs" style="margin: 13px;" ng-click="submitValue()" ng-disabled="myForm.$invalid">SubmitValue</button>
    </div>

  </form>
</body>

</html>
```